# Stopping service doesn't stop long polling in it

Tags: android, android-service, long-polling

So I have this code in my service.

```
public void longPolling(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String line = null;

    URL serverAddress = null;

    String lastModify = null;
    String etag = null;

    while (true) {

        try {
            serverAddress = new URL(url);
            // set up out communications stuff
            connection = null;

            // Set up the initial connection
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) serverAddress.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setReadTimeout(60000);

            if (lastModify != null) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since",
                        lastModify);
            }

            if (etag != null) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("If-None-Match", etag);
            }

            connection.connect();
            // read the result from the server

            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connection.getInputStream()));

            sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + '\n');
            }

            lastModify = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
            etag = connection.getHeaderField("Etag");
            String response = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(sb.toString(),
                    "UTF-8");
            sendResults(response); //sends broadcast to activities.

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            log.debug(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.debug(e);
        } finally { // close the connection, set all objects to null
            connection.disconnect();
            rd = null;
            sb = null;
            connection = null;
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine. But when user logs out off the app, Service should be stopped. But this polling doesn't stop. It kept on running even if the service is stopped.

Comment: [See if helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886874/how-to-stop-service-by-itself)

Answer (score 0):

Because you write while(true) create one variable and declare initially true and set false in onstop() method of Service and set that variable to while(yourvariable) thats it...

Comment: I thought of it. But if user force stops the service or any other task manager apps stops my service, Will onStop() be executed?

Comment: then when you want to stop method?

Comment: that's what my question is

Comment: ok i understand if you want to does not stop your method even if your service stop then just create AsyncTask class in Service and put your method in doInbackground method. thats it...

Comment: So here if your service stopped by force then your downloading progress in other background thread.which is stop after download your data.

Comment: Its already in an async task. But it will never be stopped as it is longpolling. It's not downloading any file here. It's a client for Nginx-PushStream-LongPolling.

Comment: one thing i dont understend why are you used while loop here?

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using a loop? I know it can be done with recursion too. But there is no much difference.

Comment: my que is why are you use loop? what is your requirement ?

Comment: Its longpolling. Need to poll the server continuously for updates

Comment: then user alarmmanager to restart Service if externally stop service

Comment: I am not worried about restarting service, but stop execution if service is stopped

Comment: then you have to take flag variable for indicate Service is Stopped by user and when it true just break your while loop and stop execution.

Comment: How will the app know if some taskkiller app stops my service?

Comment: Or user directly stops the service from settings>apps>running apps