# Stop service inside Service using onClickListener

Tags: android, service

I have a simple service. My problem is that `stopSelf()` does not work.

Here is my code:

```
   public class MyService extends Service {

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params;
    LayoutInflater li;

                @Override
                public void onCreate() {

                    super.onCreate();

        li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    700,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            final WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

      final View view = li.inflate(R.layout.serviceeee, null); 

         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

             imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    MyService.this.stopSelf();// doesnt work...
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Salamis! Could you please tell us what you have tried already?

Comment: i think the problem is that i dont call onDestroy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service must be stopped itself by calling stopSelf() method, once it is finishes execution. However, you can also stop a service yourself by calling stopService() method.

```
stopService(new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyService.class));
```

For stopself():

It should be called when automatically by self, like service is going to finish the work then it's called something like below, which will use this method after some time.

```
  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                //Your logic that service will perform will be placed here
                //In this example we are just looping and waits for 1000 milliseconds in each loop.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    if(isRunning){
                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                    }
                }

                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

For more, check this link which will suits your problem:-
[How to stop service by itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886874/how-to-stop-service-by-itself)

Comment: i started the service from an activity and then i kill the activity because i need only the service

Comment: ok, (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1), where is layout of imageView1?

Comment: i have just tried to use stopService inside of myActivity and still doesnt kill service!!

Comment: i think problem is not with code of stopping service, it's any other.

Comment: see my anwser and post the same code.. and i will accept your anwser

Comment: i think you solved your problem, thanks a lot but stop service do work.

Comment: my friend you helped me a lot thanks for your time i accept your answer. Have a nice day!!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and now i can kill my service

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy(){

        windowManager.removeView(view);

        super.onDestroy();  
    }
```